# How to create read-only connection pool on Eclipselink

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink

My application of Eclipselink must not modify database value.
I want eclipselink to throw some exception when not permitted operation has occured.

I found `connection-pool.read`, added it to `persistence.xml`. However `CREATE`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statement did not be unexecutable.

connection-pool.read | EclipseLink 2.4.x Java Persistence API (JPA) Extensions Reference : http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_connection_pool_read.htm#CHDDIIFD

In my understanding, `connection-pool.default` is property for the number of connections of read and write, and `connection-pool.read`(or write) is to set the number of connections individually. Is that correct understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this page: http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html

> Optimization #5 - Read Only The application is migrating from the
>   MySQL database to the Oracle database. So is only reading from MySQL.
>   When you execute a query in JPA, all of the resulting objects become
>   managed as part of the current persistence context. This is wasteful
>   in JPA, as managed objects are tracked for changes and registered with
>   the persistence context. EclipseLink provides a
>   "eclipselink.read-only"="true" query hint that allows the persistence
>   context to be bypassed. This can be used for the migration, as the
>   objects from MySQL will not be written back to MySQL.

So, try eclipselink.read-only instead of connection-pool.read

Comment: I set read-only onto EntityManager as `em.setProperty(QueryHints.READ_ONLY, HintsValue.True)`. However `persist` or `remove` operations are executed normally.
Is this correct way to set `eclipselink.read-only` hint?

Comment: The example in the referenced article sets it against the Query object, using query.setHint("eclipselink.read-only", "true").  I"ve never done this myself, but the code sample at the end should provide some guidance?